# The input of latitutde and longitude is not showing up. In the extended controls of AVD in location can someone help me with this?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, location

In the image you can see there is no Latitude, Longitude, and altitude input space.
How can I fix this?
[image: 1]

Above is the link to the concerned problem screenshot

Comment: Are you connected to internet ?. If yes try to delete this emulator and then try to create new one. This location screen relay on system's internet connection.

Comment: I tried it and the device is connected to the internet too. But still, it stays the same Lokesh.